# A noun that refers to attendees of a cocktail party

Tags: nouns

I'm looking for a noun to refer to a group of people socializing, for instance a loosely knit group of work friends gossiping at a cocktail party.

Comment: partygoers, partyers, revellers.  I don't think you will get a term specifically for a cocktail party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without inferring affinity for each other, a group of coworkers can be a [***cohort***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cohort).  It simply implies shared characteristics.  The cocktail party could have several cohorts: The workers, and the worker's spouses, the bosses, etc.

You might also consider ***milieu***.  It doesn't mean "a group."  But it does describe the environment the coworkers find themselves without inferring that the coworkers or cliquish or otherwise close knit.

> A [milieu](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/milieu) is a surrounding culture. Your family, house, neighborhood, school, and people you hang out with make up your milieu.

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

If they tend to stick together to the exclusion of others, it could be called a *[clique](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/clique)*

> A small group of people, with shared interests or other features in common, who spend time together and do not readily allow others to join them.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

This term is used in numerous settings, not just at parties.

Similarly

> - *coterie*
> - *ingroup*
> - *inner circle*
> - *set* (often preceded by an adjectival noun, such as *office set* or *smart set*)

Answer (score 1):

There is no word specifically meaning cocktail-party-goers.  However, there are some words which differentiate such a group of people from the people working at the party or those who are not there:

- Revelers
- Partyers / Partiers     [ref](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/partiers?s=t)
- Guests
- Celebrators
- Partaker
- Patrons (if at a bar or other commercial establishment)